# How to tell if a players inventory is full - Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm very new at minecraft plugin developing, in the process of learning things. I'm working on a prison plugin and created a method that should let a player know if their inventory is full. It's not working and I can't figure out why.
Code:

```
    public void invFull(Player p) {
        if (p.getInventory().contains(Material.AIR)) {

        } else {
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Your inventory is full!");
        }
    }
}
```

I've also created another method returning a boolean. This also does not work.
Code:

```
public boolean invFull(Player p) {          
        if (p.getInventory().contains(Material.AIR)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }           
}
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: @AndrewL.When I export the plugin to the plugins folder and reload the server. It just doesn't work. no message shows when it should.

Comment: How are you using the method? Use like: `if(invFull(insert_player)) { //do stuff, is full } else { //not full }`

Comment: @AndrewL.That's pretty much how I am using it. If the players inventory is not full it won't do anything. If it is full it will display the message.

Comment: The if statement is empty, doesn't do anything `if (p.getInventory().contains(Material.AIR)) {}`

Comment: @c0der Thats how I want it. Because if the inventory contains air it's not full. There is still space. That's why after the else it displays the message cuz if it doesn't contain air it is full.

Comment: @AndrewL. I thought boolean might be more efficient. The only problem with it is when I do `if (invFull() == true) { p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED  + "Your inventory is full!"); }` I get an error with the `if (invFull() == true) {` part and so that doesn't work

Comment: So how do I display the message if the boolean returns true?

Comment: Instead of having an empty `if` you could use not (`!`) : `if (! p.getInventory().contains(Material.AIR)) { 

            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Your inventory is full!");
        }`

Comment: try putting a message in the `if` block also, which says if the inventory is not full, that could help.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the issue is, that a player inventory can not contain `Material.AIR`. Try the following:

```
public boolean invFull(Player p) {          
    return p.getInventory().firstEmpty() == -1;           
}
```

I'm currently not 100% sure if this `firstEmpty()` will fail if an armor slot is empty, but i can currently not test this. If it does, another option would be:

```
public boolean invFull(Player p) {          
    return !Arrays.asList(p.getInventory().getStorageContents()).contains(null);           
}
```

Comment: To understand why `contains(Material.AIR)` doesn't work, inventory slots are of type `ItemStack` whereas `Material.AIR` is of incompatible type `Material`.  I.e. the inventory will *never* contain `Material.AIR` (or any other `Material`!)

Comment: This is simply not true. A PlayerInventory contains (like you said ItemStacks), so you are right. A PlayerInventory implements the Inventory Interface, which provides the method contains, which is overloaded for many different parameters. So there is the [`contains(Material)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/inventory/Inventory.html#contains(org.bukkit.Material)) method, which checks each ItemStack, if its Material is of the provided Type. But Material.AIR will never be in a Players Inventory, instead there are no ItemStacks -> null on an empty Inventory Slot.

Comment: That's only true when using Bukkit, which is not universally true, and the asker never mentioned using.